# Why can we substitute the exponential function while deriving the characteristic equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying the way characteristic equation works. The derivation, according to Wikipedia, follows:

We have a function $y(x)$ and an equation
$$a_n y^{(n)} + \cdots + a_1 y' + a_0 y = 0.$$

Then we substitute $$y = e^{rx}.$$

Why can we make such a substitution? I suspect we can't represent any function as $e^{rx}$. Besides it is said that $\forall z: e^{z} \neq 0$ (can you point me to a proof too), so if $\exists x_0: y(x_0) = 0$ then we can't represent this value in this substitution.

Comment: A word: ansatz (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz).

Comment: A similar technique is used to solve linear difference equations with constant coefficients. Thus $a_{n}-5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=0$ has the characteristic equation $r^{2}-5r+6=0$ and solution is of the form $a_{n}=A\cdot 2^{n}+B\cdot 3^{n}$. However in this case the characteristic eqn is not arrived by a guess but by finding the sum $\sum a_{n}x^{n}$ as a rational function of $x$ whose denominator is the characteristic polynomial. I strongly believe that there is something similar going on here in case of a differential eqn and it is definitely not based on guess.

Comment: It's just a guess. It turns out to be a good guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We only **bravely try**$^*$ to substitute $y=e^{rx}$ in

$$a_n y^{(n)} + ... + a_1 y' + a_0 y = 0. $$
We get then

$$a_n r^ne^{rx} + ... + a_1 re^{rx} + a_0 e^{rx} = 0.\tag 1$$

If we substitute $x=0$ (or if we divide both sides by $e^{rx}>0$) then we get the famous characteristic equation:
$$a_n r^n + ... + a_1 r + a_0  = 0.$$

We realize now that having solved this characteristic equation in $r$ and having substituted the solutions in $(1)$ for $r$ then we get *a series* of solutions of the differential equation.

Why?

Just imagine that $r_i$ is a solution of the characteristic equation and we substitute it for $r$ in $(1)$. Now, we have

$$a_n r_i^ne^{r_ix} + ... + a_1 r_ie^{r_ix} + a_0 e^{r_ix}=0 $$

since $e^{r_ix}>0$ for all $x$ we can divide both sides of this equation by $e^{r_ix}$. Then we do get zero exactly because $r_i$ is a solution. And , of course, this is the case for all $i$.

Note that we haven't yet determined all of the solutions. The result of our **brave action** is only *a set* of solutions.

$^*$ See the comment to the OP by  Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla.

**Edited because the last question remained unanswered**

I've just realized that the OP asked the following question at the end of his/her post:

"Why can we make such a substitution? [$e^rx$] I suspect we can't represent any function as $e^x$. Besides it is said that $\forall z \ e^z\not =0$ (can you point me to a proof too), so if $\exists \ x_0 : y(x_0)=0$ then we can't represent this value in this substitution."

1. Of courese we cannot represent any functions as $e^x$. (To be honest I do not understand this sentence.)
2. Why is it true that $\forall z :\ e^z\not =0$? The most general case is when $z=a+ib$, a complex number. Then $e^z=e^{a+ib}=e^ae^{ib}.$ Here $a$ is real so $e^a$ is never zero. The question reamins: is there a real $b$ for which $e^{ib}=0$? That is impossible because the absolute value of $e^{ib}$ is $1$ independently of the argument $b$.
3. Even if $\exists \ x_0 : y(x_0)=0$ there are functions $y$ that can be represent by a homogenuous linear differential equation. Remember, the linear combinations of the solutions of such a differential equations are solutions to it as well. Let's see an example.

Solve the following differential equation:

$$y''+y'-2y=0.$$

The characteristic equation is $r^2+r-2=0$ whose solutions are: $r_1=-2$ and $r_2=1$. That is,  $y_1(x)=e^{-2x}$ and $y_2(x)=e^x$ are certainly solutions. But the linear combinations are also solutions! So

$$y(x)=e^{-2x}-e^x$$

is a solution again. Substituting $0$ for $x$ we get that $y(0)=0$ when $y$ is a solution.

So, even if we cannot describe all kinds of functions as solutions of certain differential equations, the existence of an $x_0$ for which $y(x_0)=0$ is not an obstacle.

Comment: Let's suppose we have determined all $n$ complex roots of our characteristic equation. How can we find out whether there are no other solutions? (For example when solving $\ddot{x} = -\omega^2 x$ we find all solutions if we're using the characteristic eqn)

Comment: Our differential equation is a linear homogenous one with constant coefficients. The linear combinations of the solutions are also solutions. To prove that there are no other solutions is another issue.

Comment: So what's the use of the characteristic eqn if we want to solve the differential equation? If we can't show there are no other roots, it gives us nothing. When dealing with polynomials we can say there can be maximally $n$ distinct roots, so pointing out all $n$ roots solves the problem. Besides, these examples: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-ii-second-order-constant-coefficient-linear-equations/modes-and-the-characteristic-equation/MIT18_03SCF11_s12_2btext.pdf say "find all solutions" and the char.eqn is used. Why does this hold?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give more. Please, consult appropiate text books.

Comment: @marmistrz: I've spent some more time to better understand what your real problem might have been. I've made an attempt to clarify my answer for you.

Comment: I think you have a minor error: if you want the roots to be $-2$ and $1$ then the characteristic polynomial is $r^2-r-2$. Both solutions to $r^2+2r+1=0$ are $-1$.

Comment: @Ian: Thx; I've corrected.

Answer (score 3):

I would refer to that (setting $y= e^{rx}$) as "an educated guess".